# how to group by data into multi chunks via pyspark query?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Spark DataFrame which I need to add a column to it with some conditions.

1. select randomly a chunk of data (chunk = 1000) without replacement
2. each chunk of data should have an equal amount in the added column.

Then I will have a column which by using groupby on this column I can do some action on each chunk of data.
May you kindly, help me with this issue?
There is a sample below which I want some query like it:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# setup the spark data frame as a table
boston_sp.createOrReplaceTempView("boston")

# add train/test label and expand the data set by 3x (each num trees parameter)
full_df = spark.sql("""
  select *
  from (
    select *, case when rand() < 0.8 then 1 else 0 end as training 
    from boston
  ) b
  cross join (
      select 11 as trees union all select 20 as trees union all select 50 as trees)
""")

schema = StructType([StructField('trees', LongType(), True),
                     StructField('r_squared', DoubleType(), True)])  

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def train_RF(boston_pd):
    trees = boston_pd['trees'].unique()[0]

    # get the train and test groups 
    boston_train = boston_pd[boston_pd['training'] == 1]
    boston_test = boston_pd[boston_pd['training'] == 0] 
        
    # create data and label groups 
    y_train = boston_train['target']
    X_train = boston_train.drop(['target'], axis=1)
    y_test = boston_test['target']
    X_test = boston_test.drop(['target'], axis=1)
   
    # train a classifier 
    rf= RFR(n_estimators = trees)
    model = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # make predictions
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    r = pearsonr(y_pred, y_test)
    
    # return the number of trees, and the R value 
    return pd.DataFrame({'trees': trees, 'r_squared': (r[0]**2)}, index=[0])
  
# use the Pandas UDF
results = full_df.groupby('trees').apply(train_RF)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example to do what (I think) you wanted:

```
df = spark.range(10)

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "*",
    "int(rand() * 3) trees",
    "case when rand() < 0.8 then 1 else 0 end training"
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+--------+
| id|trees|training|
+---+-----+--------+
|  0|    1|       1|
|  1|    1|       1|
|  2|    2|       1|
|  3|    0|       1|
|  4|    1|       1|
|  5|    0|       1|
|  6|    2|       0|
|  7|    1|       1|
|  8|    2|       0|
|  9|    2|       1|
+---+-----+--------+
```

If you are using Spark, you might want to consider using the Spark ML library rather than using scikit-learn on grouped dataframes. For example, if you want to do random forest regression, you can have a look at [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor) and [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-regression) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I do not use scikit-learn and I cannot use MLlib too. The method is self-implemented and I wanna scale the algorithm for big data. Anyway, thank you for your support. I will try with your solution and get back to you